# Issue with CellCycleScoring in Seurat Saying 'Rowmeans' subscript is out of bounds

Tags: r, cell, seurat, rna-seq

For a single cell dataset in R (4.2.0), I am using my typical workflow which I never usually have any problems with.

When trying to use CellCycleScoring() from Seurat, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowMeans': subscript out of bounds
```

I have never encountered this error and other questions addressing this answer haven't helped me figure out what's going on yet, but I am not quite sure where to start (I have only been using R for a few months now, so I am not very experienced with these things) and would appreciate help from someone more familiar with this!

I tried to use the CellCycleScoring function in Seurat, but recieved an error.

Comment: Update: After scaling my data, somehow the issue was solved! Kind of strange but if someone else has this issue, maybe try normalising and scaling it first :)